# How to add DnnCssInclude from code behind?

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

I have been working on a DNN Theme. At this moment I have this code on my page.ascx:

```
<dnn:DnnCssInclude runat="server" FilePath="css/mydnnstyles.css" PathNameAlias="SkinPath" Priority="3" />
```

But how can I add the same control from the code behind (page.ascx.cs)?
something like:

```
page?.Controls.Add(new DnnCssInclude
        {
            ...
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use the ClientResourceManager calls:

```
ClientResourceManager.RegisterStyleSheet(Page, "/portals/_default/skins/PATH/FILENAME.css", FileOrder.Css.DefaultCss);
```

You'll need to have references to

```
using DotNetNuke.Web.Client;
using DotNetNuke.Web.Client.ClientResourceManagement;
```

Comment: My only concern here is if after updating "FILENAME.css" and increasing the HOST VERSION clients still will use "FILENAME.css" from their browser's cache?

Comment: @ErickLangfordXenes, the Client Resource Manager will add the client resources version to the CSS request with a query string, so help break the cache in the users' browser.  If you configure the Client Resource Manager to combine CSS & scripts, then the request will be for a hash of the contents of the combines files, so a change in a file will result in a new URL